# What does the "box" keyword do?

Tags: rust

In Rust, we can use the `Box<T>` type to allocate things on the heap.  This type is used to safely abstract pointers to heap memory.  `Box<T>` is provided by the Rust standard library.

I was curious about how `Box<T>` allocation is implemented, so I found [its source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/liballoc/boxed.rs).  Here is the code for `Box<T>::new` (as of Rust 1.0):

```rust
impl<T> Box<T> {
    /// Allocates memory on the heap and then moves `x` into it.
    /// [...]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn new(x: T) -> Box<T> {
        box x
    }
}
```

The only line in the implementation returns the value `box x`.  This `box` keyword is not explained anywhere in the official documentation; in fact, it is only mentioned briefly on the [`std::boxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html) documentation page.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**NOTE:** This reply is a bit old. Since it talks about internals and unstable features, things have changed a little bit. The basic mechanism remains the same though, so the answer is still capable of *explaining* the underlying mechanisms of `box`.

What does `box x` usually uses to allocate and free memory?

The answer is the functions marked with lang items `exchange_malloc` for allocation and `exchange_free` for freeing. You can see the implementation of those in the default standard library at [heap.rs#L112](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cec980a1a706fd6afc27dd54c1eed7c51800d753/src/liballoc/heap.rs#L112) and [heap.rs#L125](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cec980a1a706fd6afc27dd54c1eed7c51800d753/src/liballoc/heap.rs#L125).

In the end the `box x` syntax depends on the following lang items:

- `owned_box` on a `Box` struct to encapsulate the allocated pointer. This struct does not need a `Drop` implementation, it is implemented automatically by the compiler.
- `exchange_malloc` to allocate the memory.
- `exchange_free` to free the previously allocated memory.

This can be effectively seen in the [lang items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html) chapter of the unstable rust book using this `no_std` example:

```
#![feature(lang_items, box_syntax, start, no_std, libc)]
#![no_std]

extern crate libc;

extern {
    fn abort() -> !;
}

#[lang = "owned_box"]
pub struct Box<T>(*mut T);

#[lang = "exchange_malloc"]
unsafe fn allocate(size: usize, _align: usize) -> *mut u8 {
    let p = libc::malloc(size as libc::size_t) as *mut u8;

    // malloc failed
    if p as usize == 0 {
        abort();
    }

    p
}
#[lang = "exchange_free"]
unsafe fn deallocate(ptr: *mut u8, _size: usize, _align: usize) {
    libc::free(ptr as *mut libc::c_void)
}

#[start]
fn main(argc: isize, argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    let x = box 1;

    0
}

#[lang = "stack_exhausted"] extern fn stack_exhausted() {}
#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop {} }
```

Notice how `Drop` was not implemented for the `Box` struct? Well let's see the LLVM IR generated for `main`:

```
define internal i64 @_ZN4main20hbd13b522fdb5b7d4ebaE(i64, i8**) unnamed_addr #1 {
entry-block:
  %argc = alloca i64
  %argv = alloca i8**
  %x = alloca i32*
  store i64 %0, i64* %argc, align 8
  store i8** %1, i8*** %argv, align 8
  %2 = call i8* @_ZN8allocate20hf9df30890c435d76naaE(i64 4, i64 4)
  %3 = bitcast i8* %2 to i32*
  store i32 1, i32* %3, align 4
  store i32* %3, i32** %x, align 8
  call void @"_ZN14Box$LT$i32$GT$9drop.103617h8817b938807fc41eE"(i32** %x)
  ret i64 0
}
```

The `allocate` (`_ZN8allocate20hf9df30890c435d76naaE`) was called as expected to build the `Box`, meanwhile... Look! A `Drop` method for the `Box` (`_ZN14Box$LT$i32$GT$9drop.103617h8817b938807fc41eE`)! Let's see the IR for this method:

```
define internal void @"_ZN14Box$LT$i32$GT$9drop.103617h8817b938807fc41eE"(i32**) unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  %1 = load i32** %0
  %2 = ptrtoint i32* %1 to i64
  %3 = icmp ne i64 %2, 2097865012304223517
  br i1 %3, label %cond, label %next

next:                                             ; preds = %cond, %entry-    block
  ret void

cond:                                             ; preds = %entry-block
  %4 = bitcast i32* %1 to i8*
  call void @_ZN10deallocate20he2bff5e01707ad50VaaE(i8* %4, i64 4, i64 4)
  br label %next
}
```

There it is, `deallocate` (`ZN10deallocate20he2bff5e01707ad50VaaE`) being called on the compiler generated Drop!

Notice even on the [standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cec980a1a706fd6afc27dd54c1eed7c51800d753/src/liballoc/boxed.rs) the `Drop` trait is not implemented by user-code. Indeed `Box` is a bit of a magical struct.

Answer (score 18):

Before `box` was marked as unstable, it was used as a shorthand for calling `Box::new`. However, it's always been intended to be able to allocate *arbitrary types*, such as `Rc`, or to use arbitrary allocators. Neither of these have been finalized, so it wasn't marked as stable for the 1.0 release. This is done to prevent supporting a bad decision for all of Rust 1.x.

For further reference, you can read the [RFC that changed the "placement new" syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/0806be4f282144cfcd55b1d20284b43f87cbe1c6/text/0809-box-and-in-for-stdlib.md) and also feature gated it.

Comment: So currently (in the implementation above) `box x` is placement-new syntax?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty, yes, it is placement new syntax which is currently hardcoded to work with `Box`es only.

Comment: So eventually `Box` will be treated no more specially than any type I can create, and it will simply use other (post-1.0) language features.

Answer (score 10):

`box` does exactly what `Box::new()` does - it creates an owned box.

I believe that you can't find implementation of `box` keyword because currently it is hardcoded to work with owned boxes, and `Box` type is a lang item:

```
#[lang = "owned_box"]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[fundamental]
pub struct Box<T>(Unique<T>);
```

Because it is a lang item, the compiler has special logic to handle its instantiation which it can link with `box` keyword.

I believe that the compiler delegates box allocation to functions in [`alloc::heap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/heap/) module.

As for what `box` keyword does and supposed to do in general, Shepmaster's answer describes perfectly.

Comment: _box does exactly what Box::new() does._ That is only true in theory, right? If I understand it correctly, there is a the practical difference that [`box` can bypass stack allocation, but `Box::new` doesn't](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58570).