# How to allocate structs on the heap without taking up space on the stack in stable Rust?

Tags: rust

In this code...

```rust
struct Test { a: i32, b: i64 }
    
fn foo() -> Box<Test> {              // Stack frame:
    let v = Test { a: 123, b: 456 }; // 12 bytes
    Box::new(v)                      // `usize` bytes (`*const T` in `Box`)
}
```

... as far as I understand (ignoring possible optimizations), `v` gets allocated on the stack and then copied to the heap, before being returned in a `Box`.

And this code...

```rust
fn foo() -> Box<Test> {
    Box::new(Test { a: 123, b: 456 })
}
```

...shouldn't be any different, presumably, since there should be a temporary variable for struct allocation (assuming compiler doesn't have any special semantics for the instantiation expression inside `Box::new()`).

I've found [Do values in return position always get allocated in the parents stack frame or receiving Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506225/5877243). Regarding my specific question, it only proposes the experimental `box` syntax, but mostly talks about compiler optimizations (copy elision).

So my question remains: using **stable** Rust, how does one allocate `struct`s directly on the heap, without relying on compiler optimizations?

Comment: this will be a totally absurd thing to do let the compiler to the magic for you. But if you want https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Alloc.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I strongly disagree about absurdity. I think any "magic" is inherently unreliable, let alone that it requires knowledge of compiler internals. Moreover, when performance is critical, or resources are limited, all memory operations are important, and in this particular case it would be nice to be sure that no unnecessary operations are performed.

Comment: I should also note that even though the provided link technically solves the problem, I'm pretty sure it's not the idiomatic way. It's just too low level. I could've called an allocator directly for that matter, probably, and get the raw pointer to the heap. I'm pretty sure there must be a language-level (or "stdlib-level") construct for that.

Comment: An other "solution" is to use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new_uninit that new so I didn't think to it before, still low level in my opinion. But use this to "avoid using stack" is stupid.

Comment: @Stargatdoeur in debug the compiler will not do the magic for you and you will get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Rust 1.39, there seems to be only one way in stable to allocate memory on the heap directly - by using [`std::alloc::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) (note that the docs state that it is expected to be deprecated). It's reasonably unsafe.

Example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    a: i64,
    b: &'static str,
}

fn main() {
    use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};

    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::new::<Test>();
        let ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut Test;

        (*ptr).a = 42;
        (*ptr).b = "testing";

        let bx = Box::from_raw(ptr);

        println!("{:?}", bx);
    }
}
```

This approach is used in the unstable method [`Box::new_uninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new_uninit).

It turns out there's even a crate for avoiding `memcpy` calls (among other things): [copyless](https://crates.io/crates/copyless). This crate also uses an approach based on this.

Comment: Shouldn't this use [`std::ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html) instead of assignment with `=` to not drop the old value at that location?

Comment: This code causes undefined behavior when it attempts to assign the values for `a` and `b` as it constructs a reference to the fields `a` and `b`, but those have uninitialized junk in them. There's no way to do this correctly until [raw references](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2582-raw-reference-mir-operator.html) are stabilized.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach that would be **better**, but it's not needed in _this specific case_ because `i64` and `&str` don't have a `Drop` implementation.

Comment: @Shepmaster Whoops, sorry, I misread `&str` as `String`, hence my concern.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be looking for the [`box_syntax`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/box-syntax.html) feature, however as of Rust 1.39.0 it is not stable and only available with a nightly compiler. It also seems like this feature will not be stabilized any time soon, and might have a different design if it ever gets stabilized.

On a nightly compiler, you can write:

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]

struct Test { a: i32, b: i64 }

fn foo() -> Box<Test> {
    box Test { a: 123, b: 456 }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However, I was asking about *stable* Rust, and as it turns out, there is a solution for it, albeit not as elegant as this syntax. Moreover, since this syntax is basically a compiler-internal feature (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49733), I reckon stable solution will be such for a long time.

Comment: The box syntax is perma unstable as of 2022-04-27: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49733#issuecomment-1111283609

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to allocate directly to the heap without `box`?

No. If there was, it wouldn't need a language change.

People tend to avoid this by using the unstable syntax indirectly, such as by using one of the standard containers which, in turn, uses it internally.

See also:

- [How to allocate arrays on the heap in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30242770/155423)
- [Is there any way to allocate a standard Rust array directly on the heap, skipping the stack entirely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53691012/155423)
- [What does the box keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30352802/155423)
- [What is the <- symbol in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762055/155423)

Answer (score 2):

With Rust 1.51 and above one can use `addr_of_mut` to avoid intermediary references as in [mrnaterivers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368947/442760), the `Allocator` is still unstable so the use of `std::alloc::alloc` remains.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    a: i64,
    b: &'static str,
}

fn main() {
    use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};
    use std::ptr::addr_of_mut;

    let layout = Layout::new::<Test>();

    let bx = unsafe {
        let ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut Test;

        addr_of_mut!((*ptr).a).write(42);
        addr_of_mut!((*ptr).b).write("testing");

        Box::from_raw(ptr)
    };
    println!("{:?}", bx);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same problem. Based on the answers here and other places, I wrote a simple function for heap allocation:

```
pub fn unsafe_allocate<T>() -> Box<T> {
    let mut grid_box: Box<T>;
    unsafe {
        use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};
        let layout = Layout::new::<T>();
        let ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut T;
        grid_box = Box::from_raw(ptr);
    }
    return grid_box;
}
```

This will create a region in memory automatically sized after `T` and unsafely convince Rust that that memory region is an actual `T` value. The memory may contain arbitrary data; you should not assume all values are 0.

Example use:

```
let mut triangles: Box<[Triangle; 100000]> = unsafe_allocate::<[Triangle; 100000]>();
```

Comment: This code is non-idiomatic and improperly uses `unsafe` code. This can trivially be used to introduce undefined behavior.

Comment: But it's the only way? All the other answers say that using `alloc` is the way to go, and this seems to be the most safe way to use `alloc`

Comment: Even if I'm late, I think what Shepmaster means is that this function can be used to [cause UB in safe Rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=084ec3472e1f4700e118c46d34d57b56), it is *unsound*, at the very least it has to be defined as an `unsafe` function.

Comment: @cafce25 This is literally what the libraries mentioned do internally

Comment: I don't quite follow that argument, they have that code so this is somehow sound? It's not.

Comment: Marking the function as unsafe would probably be a improvement